# how to change icon google font, but not change text in the tabs

Tags: html, css, icons

i have some problem with the code..

i want to change icon color is red/orange, but not change text color when active.

if tabs/button active, that color must be white, if tabs not active icon color orange..

i just have problem with icon color.. i try change color with hover but solved my problem, i think i have some wrong with the code, do you help me please.. thanks guys..

what I want is like in the picture
[it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbUfq.png)

help please..
thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://belipulsa.co.id/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/css/widget-icon-list.min.css">      
      
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
</style>

<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: none;

  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 16px;


}
.active, .tab button:hover {
  background-color: #FF9B23;
  color: white;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #FF9B23;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #FF9B23;
color: white;
}

/*======================*/
.tab2 {
  float: right;
  border: none;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab2 button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 16px;

}
.active, .tab2 button:hover {
  background-color: #FF9B23;
  color: white;
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab2 button:hover {
  background-color: #FF9B23;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab2 button.active {
  background-color: #FF9B23;
}
/*======================*/

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: center;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: none;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.p1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .p2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .p3 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .p4 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .p5 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .p6 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

.material-icons.md-inactive { color: red; }
.material-icons { color: black; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab">

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'daftar')" id="defaultOpen">
  
<span class="material-icons">face</span>
<span class="material-icons">face</span>
                            
  <p class="p1">Daftar Gratis Tanpa Biaya</p>
  
<p class="x1">Hanya bermodalkan smartphone dan koneksi internet Anda dapat melakukan transaksi tanpa dipungut biaya registrasi.
  
  </button>
  
  
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'trx')"><span class="material-icons md-dark md-inactive">calendar_today</span><p class="p2">Beragam Cara Transaksi</p>Nikmati beragam metode transaksi dengan mudah melalui aplikasi android, WhatsApp, Telegram tanpa kode produk.</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'cs')"><span class="material-icons md-dark md-inactive">calendar_today</span><p class="p3">24 Jam Layanan</p>Kemudahan bertransaksi dan layanan bantuan customer service selama 24 jam non stop dari aplikasi Raja Payment.</button>
</div>
<div class="tab2">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'sms')"><span class="material-icons md-dark md-inactive">calendar_today</span><p class="p4">SMS Report to End User</p>Pelanggan Anda akan menerima notifikasi SMS yang berisi nama outlet/konter Anda setelah transaksi berhasil.</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'rekap')"><span class="material-icons md-dark md-inactive">calendar_today</span><p class="p5">Rekap Piutang Transaksi</p>Anda dapat membuat dan mengelola laporan piutang dari transaksi yang dilakukan dalam periode tertentu.</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'bonus')"><span class="material-icons md-dark md-inactive">calendar_today</span><p class="p6">Bonus Transaksi Terbanyak</p>Dapatkan bonus bagi yang berhasil melakukan transaksi terbanyak dalam periode tertentu.</button>
</div>

<div id="daftar" class="tabcontent">
  <img src="https://belipulsa.co.id/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Mockup-3.png">
</div>
<div id="trx" class="tabcontent">
  <img src="http://kemoboydesign.com/themes/leon/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/features-iphone-6-slide-3.png">
</div>
<div id="cs" class="tabcontent">
    <img src="http://kemoboydesign.com/themes/leon/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/features-iphone-6-slide-2.png">
</div>
<div id="sms" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>SMS</h3>
  <p>4.</p>
</div>
<div id="rekap" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>REKAP</h3>
  <p>5.</p>
</div>
<div id="bonus" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>BONUS</h3>
  <p>6.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi the buttons seem to be working as described for me?

Comment: i think is not the button, but tab.

Comment: All working perfectly on my end

Comment: yes, but my icon not perfect...

Comment: i want if my tab select/active, icon color is white... but tab not active, icon color is orange..

Comment: in your css 2 last lines, put material icons inactive to orange, and material icons to white

Comment: not working, you try..

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).